# Why is Magento not picking up my theme template file for transactional email order?

Tags: email, templates, magento

I made some template changes to Magento's **New Order** transactional email template in the backend. The textual changes at the top of the email (in the "thanks for your order..." section) worked fine. But when I change the templates for the order details, they are not appearing in my email.

I have created two files within my template which I thought would override the email:

1. `app/design/frontend/default/mythemehere/template/email/order/items.phtml`
2. `app/design/frontend/default/mythemehere/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml`

These are referenced in my sales.xml file in `app/design/frontend/default/mythemehere/layout`

```
<sales_email_order_items>
    <block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="email/order/items.phtml">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_default</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_grouped</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
            <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="2" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
            <action method="setValueProperties"><value>align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
            <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml">
                <action method="setIsPlaneMode"><value>1</value></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </block>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" />
</sales_email_order_items>
```

However, when I place my order, I get the base template in the email.

If I commit the Cardinal Sin in Magento of overriding base template files (`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order ...`), lo and behold, I see my changes! Seems Magento is very keen to use its base template.

I have overridden other templates in the sales section (eg: `sales/order/view.phtml`, `sales/order/print.phtml`), and various posts on Magento's forums indicate I'm doing the right thing in concept. But alas! It's just not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I discovered that the emails will use the /app/design/frontend/default/default templates before the 'base' templates. So if you copy the base templates into the default/default folder your files will not be overwritten on update.

However it is still not ideal as this is still outside your theme folder, however it is better than using 'base' files. I still haven't found a true solution.

Answer (score 2):

To use your custom theme file for order email  "app/design/frontend/default/mythemehere/template/email/order/items.phtml"

In the admin go to System->configuration->design

Select your website from the top left 
Now in the themes template uncheck the checkbok and add the theme name.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of situation happens because if we mention wrong values under `System>Configuration>General -> Design` section

[image: Magento default settings]

We can have following two scenarios.

1) Default package with custom design

[image: default package_custom theme]

[image: default package_custom theme_directory]

2) Custom package

[image: custom package]

[image: custom package directory]

If we do not fill correct values under **Current Package Name** field  then issue mentioned in the question will occur.

It happened with me when I was using a **custom package** but had given value as
 **default** under **Current Package Name** field.

We should configure the theme properly so that Magento can follow theme fallback properly.

Answer (score 0):

Overwriting templates in `base/default` and `default/default` [is strongly discouraged](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magentos-theme-hierarchy#3.2), because updating Magento will overwrite those directories.

What worked for me (with emails) is to put the modified files under `app/design/frontend/your_design_package/default/templates/`.